# Using PhantomJS on host without root access

Tags: php, linux, binary, hosting, phantomjs

I have been struggling with this for a long time now so I decided to ask it here.

I want to use PhantomJS on my host that does not have root access. Right now I am using 000webhost.com to test things, it is `Apache ver. 2.2.19 (Unix)` and I uploaded `phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2` to the `pulic_html/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686.tar/` file.

1. Should this work or do I need root access to use PhantomJS.
2. If it should work is it because my php executing it is wrong `exec('http://example.com/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686.tar/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2 http://example.com/countdown.js');`
3. Will VPS hosting with root access work.

As you can see I am really confused and any help will be great.

Comment: What are you trying to use phantomjs for? you need to untar the file you have downloaded `tar xvf phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686.tar` first of all. There is README.md file in the top directory when extracted which will give you some ideas for use. You don't need to be root to use it

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn Thank You very much for the great help. I feel like I got it now but unfortunately it still does not work. This is what my FileZilla looks like: test folder --> countdown.js fileType: JScript Script File, phantomjs filetype: file, phpphantom.php filetype: php file. (all three files in test folder) all with permissions set to 777. When I visit the phpphantom.php I just get the text which is `exec("phantomjs countdown.js");`. Am I doing something wrong? thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem is 000webhost.com does not have ssh access so I was unable to properly untar. Also exec is disabled on their shared hosting. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: You can install the phatomjs with composer thanks to https://packagist.org/packages/jakoch/phantomjs-installer

Answer (score 0):

Usually executing applications in a shared hosting environment isn't the best practice and your hosting provider may not allow it. I would recommend getting a VPS if you need to run PhantomJS since you will have full control over how you run your applications.

Running an application as root and calling it from PHP is a **bad** idea. If your system is compromised, then the attacker has root access. Create an account with restricted privileges on your VPS for running PhantomJS. Then you can proceed to call PhantomJS from PHP using `exec`.